# Reduce woocommerce excerpt length?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So, i am currently working with the theme Neighborhood and it seems like when i choose to show description under the products it shows the whole thing.

Is there any way to limit the Excerpt length for that? I've tried some different codes that i've put into funtions.php and also tried to edit the short-description.php in the woocommerce folder to no avail.

i've tried this code

```
<?php $excerpt = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );
echo substr($length,0, 10);
?>
```

Is it something that i am missing here i wonder?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a custom function

```
function get_the_twitter_excerpt(){
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$the_str = substr($excerpt, 0, 20);
return $the_str;
}
```

you should be able to put the above into your functions and this

```
<?php echo 'Excerpt: '.get_the_twitter_excerpt(); ?>
```

into your loop.

Comment: Well this does not seem to work either. The full description still shows unfortunately. 

When i'm googling it seems that most people only use the simple code that i posted but for me it isn't working...

Comment: May be an issue with theme.

Comment: Just to be sure, where do i put the last code that you posted? I posted it in woocommerce.php, is that right?

And yes, i am working with a child theme. =)

Comment: you need to put it into function.php of you child theme thats it

Comment: Yeah, but i cant add another <?php tag inside the one that starts the functions.php? At least for me since i get an error...

Comment: you can add no problem with that you need to do it like this ,?> <?php ?> <?php

Comment: Thanks for your tips man, but it seems that it is not working still... Might be a problem/conflict with the theme =/.

Comment: I think we need to try in single product discription page